# How to use HTML code to bold or possibly increase the font size for sprintf within shiny context

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to bold or possibly increase the font size for my sprintf. I tried the code below but it did not work. In the code below, the "<strong" becomes part of the label instead of bolding the text. How can I fix this? Thanks, Nader

```
aes(color = Disability, 
        shape = Disability, 
        group = Disability, 
                text = sprintf("<strong> Year: %g </strong> <br>Age at Death: %g", 
                       Year, AgeatDeath))+
```

Comment: (1) Nader, I *am* trying to help. Your question is very difficult to answer as you have asked it, so I'm trying to get some clarity. (2) I don't believe anything I've suggested so far requires experience in formal CS. If so, I apologize, it's neither my intent nor necessary. (3) You haven't asked something *wrong*, you've asked something that may be answerable but requires more *context*. `ggplot2` within shiny typically behaves the same as `ggplot2` does outside of shiny, so your "shiny context" may be a red herring. I don't know, because your claims and your code are not detailed enough.

Comment: As for *"please move on"*, certainly, I won't force my advice on anybody. May I suggest, though, that you heed advice given by these strangers? Occasionally it is well-meaning and intended to either (a) answer your question directly, or (b) help you clear up questions about your question that enable *somebody* to help you. Have a good day.

Comment: It was the matter of using <b> instead of <strong>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to bold the text:

```
aes(color = Disability, 
            shape = Disability, 
            group = Disability, 
                    text = sprintf("<b> Year: %g </b> <br>Age at Death: %g", 
                           Year, AgeatDeath))+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to change the color:

```
aes(color = Disability, 
        shape = Disability, 
        group = Disability, 
                text = sprintf("<b style='color: mediumblue'> Year: %g <br>Age at Death: %g </b>", 
                       Year, AgeatDeath))+
```